# Deleting the first element in a structure

Tags: c++, struct, delete-operator

I have a code where I'm trying to delete the first id in a structure. It used to work, but now it just returns "ЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭЭ" (repeated russian letter). I tried reinstalling VS, didn't help. I know it works because I tried it on an online compiler.
These two warnings also point to the delete function, which I'm guessing is the problem. 
Warning C4156   deletion of an array expression without using the array form of 'delete'; array form substituted
Warning C4154   deletion of an array expression; conversion to pointer supplied

Here is the code itslef:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma warning (disable: 4703) //disables warning of uninitialized variable j
using namespace std;
#define  MAXDL    9      
struct el_sp
{
    char  id[MAXDL];
    struct el_sp* sled;
};
void  vkl(struct el_sp** p, char t_id[]) //enters the entered ID's from keyboard into the struct
{
    struct el_sp* pt,
        * k, * j;
    pt = (struct el_sp*)malloc(sizeof(struct el_sp));
    strcpy_s(pt->id, t_id);
    if (*p == NULL || strcmp(pt->id, (*p)->id) < 0)
    {
        pt->sled = *p; *p = pt;
    }
    else
    {
        k = *p;
        while (k != NULL && strcmp(pt->id, k->id) >= 0)
        {
            j = k; k = k->sled;
        }
        j->sled = pt; pt->sled = k;
    }
}

void pech_sp(struct el_sp* p) //prints the struct
{
    struct el_sp* i;
    char* o;
    printf("\Result:\n");
    for (i = p; i != NULL; i = i->sled)
        puts(i->id);
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    struct el_sp* p;
    unsigned  n;
    unsigned  i;
    char t_id[MAXDL];

    printf("\nEnter the amount of identificators\n n=");
    scanf_s("%u", &n);
    getchar();
    p = NULL;
    printf("Enter the identificators (press enter after each one)\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        gets_s(t_id);
        vkl(&p, t_id);
    }
    delete p->id;
    pech_sp(p);
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Delete does the same thing whatever i try, in any code
P.S.S. Sorry for bad formatting, it's the way our prof needs it

Comment: Also initialize your variables, do not disable the error checking. Your app will malfunction if you do not

Comment: Since you are programming in C++: 1) The keyword `struct` is not necessary when declaring variables or pointers.  2) Prefer to use `new` for dynamic memory; the `malloc` does not call constructors. 3) Prefer to use `std::string`, as it manage dynamic memory for you (and it's easy to pass and copy).

Comment: Do not do `delete p->id`.  The `id` field of the structure is not dynamically allocated.

Comment: Consider passing the pointers by reference.  Adding a level of indirection opens up possibilities for more issues (defects).

Comment: Are you really sure you want to disable uninitialized variables warnings? That's one of the most useful warnings in my opinion.

Comment: *"it's the way our prof needs it"* -- please note that we are not your professor. You are allowed to reformat your code for us. In fact, it might be appreciated. In a similar vein, since we are not your professor, you are allowed/encouraged to simplify your code to a [mre].

Comment: @user4581301 well, I tried j = NULL, nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `delete p->id`. It serves no purpose except to crash your program: neither it nor the struct it is in was allocated by `new`.

Also, never use `delete` to try to free `malloc`ed memory, or `free` to free `new`ed memory.

Did you want to delete the entire first node? Then do something like

```
el_sp *oldp = p;
p = p->next;
free(oldp);
```

Deleting a node in the middle is actually a bit easier. Use "chasing pointers" that point to the previous element (`prev`) and the current element (`cur`). If `cur` is the node you want to delete, simply do

```
prev->next->next = cur->next;
delete cur;
```

(Assuming you allocate nodes with `new`, which you should!)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I'm still trying to figure out why it didn't work on my pc but works in an online compiler.
And how would I be able to delete a certain node in the middle without deleting the first ones?

Comment: If it seemed to "work", that is entirely by accident. Trying to `delete` or `free` memory that was not allocated with the correct allocator is the very definition of Undefined Behavior. As for deleting in the middle, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that sometimes professors want things their way, but it's just as important to know what would be the most straightforward way to achieve your goals.

That's what I came up with. Note that there's no manual memory management, the sorting is automated, and you can easily replace the container type. In most cases the vector will be perfectly adequate - the list should only be used if the benchmarks show that you get better performance. In most cases - you won't (contrary to what professors may tell you: trust reality over teachings).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <clocale>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct El_Sp
{
    std::string id;
};

#if 1
using El_Spy = std::vector<El_Sp>;
#else
using El_Spy = std::list<El_Sp>;
#endif

template <> struct std::less<El_Sp>
{
    bool operator()(const El_Sp &l, const El_Sp &r) const
    { return l.id < r.id; }
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, El_Sp &el_sp)
{
    return in >> el_sp.id;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const El_Sp &el_sp)
{
    return out << el_sp.id;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const El_Spy &el_spy)
{
    for (auto &el : el_spy)
        out << el << '\n';
    return out;
}

template <typename Container, typename T, typename Pred = std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
auto insert_sorted(Container &cont, T &&item, Pred pred = {})
{
    return cont.insert(
        std::upper_bound(std::begin(cont), std::end(cont), std::as_const(item), pred),
           std::forward<T>(item));
}

void enter_id(El_Spy &el_spy)
{
    El_Sp el;
    std::cin >> el;
    insert_sorted(el_spy, el);
}

int main()
{
    El_Spy el_spy;

    std::setlocale(0, "");
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cout << "Введите количество идентификаторов n=";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "Введите идентификаторы. Нажмите Enter после каждого.\n";
    while (n--)
        enter_id(el_spy);

    std::cout << "Идентификаторы:\n" << el_spy;
}
```

Example session:

```
Введите количество идентификаторов n=3                                                                                                          
Введите идентификаторы. Нажмите Enter после каждого.                                                                                            
Алла                                                                                                                                            
Дарья                                                                                                                                           
Вера                                                                                                                                            
Идентификаторы:                                                                                                                                 
Алла                                                                                                                                            
Вера                                                                                                                                            
Дарья
```

When using `std::vector`, the insertion sort isn't really necessary - you could use `std::sort` after all identifiers have been entered:

```
int main()
{
    std::setlocale(0, "");
    size_t n = 0;
    std::cout << "Введите количество идентификаторов n=";
    std::cin >> n;

    El_Spy el_spy(n);
    std::cout << "Введите идентификаторы. Нажмите Enter после каждого.\n";
    for (auto &el_sp : el_spy)
        std::cin >> el_sp;

    std::sort(std::begin(el_spy), std::end(el_spy), std::less<El_Sp>());

    std::cout << "Идентификаторы:\n" << el_spy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct el_sp
{
   char  id[MAXDL];
   struct el_sp* sled;
};
```

`id` is a statically allocated array. It cannot be deleted.

```
  delete p->id;
```

The above is wrong. Deleting a pointer whose memory is not allocated by `new` leads to undefined behaviour.

You should have

```
  delete p;
```

And after deletion, you should not use `p`. So `pech_sp` should be called before rather than after.

```
pech_sp(p);
delete p;
```

Comment: But I need to output the list with the deleted node, how do I do that without calling it after delete?

Comment: @DaniAli   What do you mean "output the list with the deleted node"?